# Error with using less and less-loader in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, less

I installed less and less-loader with yarn. When I use `<style lang="less" scoped>` in /pages/index.vue got this error

nuxt(^2.15.8)
less(^4.1.1)
less-loader(^10.0.1)

**Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js): TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function at Object.lessLoader**

I removed the node_module file and also package-lock.json file and reinstalled them but I got this error again.

Comment: I used something like this in nuxt and it's OK with no error but in every vue file I got error for less-loader. It resolved with downgrading less-loader.

Comment: Pretty much my answer so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem resolved by downgrading less-loader to v7.3.0.

From v8.0.0 of less-loader, the `minimum supported webpack version is 5` and nuxt 2.15.8 is not using webpack version 5.

[less-loader v8.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

Comment: Oh yes I made a mistake. I meant nuxt 2.15.8 is not using webpack version 5. Thanks for your comment!